# java.lang.SecurityException: open3: Neither user 10060 nor current process has android.permission.USE_SIP

Tags: android, sip

I am referring SIP tutorial on android developer site here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html

As mentioned on this page there is a relevant demo app for this as SIPDemo which I found from github. (Not from official google example page, not sure why it is missing from there)

I configured the project in Android Studio and run it on mobile as well as Genymotion emulator.

The app has settings page where user can input Sip username, password and domain info. After I enter the info to the app, i see this error.

```
life.gwl.sipdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: life.gwl.sipdemo, PID: 16877
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {life.gwl.sipdemo/life.gwl.sipdemo.WalkieTalkieActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: open3: Neither user 10060 nor current process has android.permission.USE_SIP.
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1388)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: open3: Neither user 10060 nor current process has android.permission.USE_SIP.
                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                                                                      at android.net.sip.ISipService$Stub$Proxy.open3(ISipService.java:241)
                                                                      at android.net.sip.SipManager.open(SipManager.java:234)
                                                                      at life.gwl.sipdemo.WalkieTalkieActivity.initializeLocalProfile(WalkieTalkieActivity.java:170)
                                                                      at life.gwl.sipdemo.WalkieTalkieActivity.initializeManager(WalkieTalkieActivity.java:136)
                                                                      at life.gwl.sipdemo.WalkieTalkieActivity.onStart(WalkieTalkieActivity.java:105)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:6299)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6304)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1388) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I have added below permissions to AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<!-- permission-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

If I use the same SIP credentials with the apps like CSipSimple, it is working properly.

Comment: seems like you are providing wrong information to access permission.clean the project and try to provide exact information

Comment: It looks like the problem is with <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" /> permission. But i am not able to solve it or find any example app on internet which can help me solve it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have set targetSdkVersion to 23 which means that you must handle the permission requests at run-time.
[More details](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)

The easy solution is to just set the  targetSdkVersion to 22 in your app manifest.